# Is it possible to use NSURLCache to rate limit outgoing HTTP requests on the client side?

Tags: ios, macos, http, http-caching, nsurlcache

Is it possible to set up a **"rate limiting"** caching policy using 
`NSURLRequest`, `NSURLSession` and `NSURLCache`.

*i.e.Only fire off the same request 1 time in a given time period, perhaps 1 second*

So if I fire off multiples of the same exact request in a given time period, only 1 request will be fired off in realty.

Subsequent requests will:

**A)** Be ignored and never fire off, IF the first request is still waiting for a response OR the first request responded and the response was cached but the timeout threshold has not been reached.

**B)** Will fire if the time between the first request that hit the host and now is greater than or equal to the the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Not with caching, but you could do this by implementing a custom `NSURLProtocol` subclass.